# Does the heartbleed vulnerability affect the SPDY protocol?

Tags: security, web, openssl, spdy, heartbleed-bug

I am running a production environment using SPDY protocol. Can anyone tell me if I am vulnerable, here is a link to my production environement and if so, how can I fix it:

[IslandFactory.eu](https://islandfactory.eu)

Comment: `SPDY` is a higher level protocol, and it requires SSL/TLS. Its similar to asking if Heartbleed affects `HTTPS`. The problem is lower down in TLS.

Comment: It affects TLS/SSL, and therefore any protocol layered over it. We don't need a question like this per protocol.

Comment: @jww It's off-topic all right, but because it isn't about programming. It's not about software version or administration or patching. Not every Heartbleed question is about that. Please don't shotgun all Heartbleed questions the same way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, for SPDY protocol ***implementations and configurations*** that reference the OpenSSL library version 1.0.1 before version 1.0.1g, but it’s otherwise not specific to the SPDY protocol, itself.